# getting error Call to a member function result() on boolean when i try to use group_by function in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

When i try to use group_by function select query not working, and i am getting error `Call to a member function result()`, without group by query is working, i can't fix this issue ? can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? here i have added my whole query

```
$query = $this->db->select('s.*,b.*,c.*,i.*')
                 ->from('sales s')
                 ->join('biller b','s.biller_id=b.biller_id','inner')
                 ->join('customer c','s.customer_id=c.customer_id','inner')
                 ->join('invoice i ','s.sales_id=i.sales_id','inner')
                         ->group_by('sales_id');
        $data = $query->get()->result();
                return $data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the `sales_id` column name on this line is ambiguous :

```
->group_by('sales_id');
```

So you could change it either using `sales.sales_id` or `invoice.sales_id` :

```
->group_by('s.sales_id');
```